# What does this notation means : $[\frac{1}{N}]_{N \times 1}$?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

I am doing research on PageRank, and in one paper this notation was in a formula :

$M' = cM + (1-c) \times [\frac{1}{N}]_{_{N \times 1}}$

I have searched google for about an hour now but nothing came up. I am guessing it is a vector of size $N$, but I could be completely wrong, and as such I cannot understand the formula.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be a vector with elements $a_i \in \{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1,/4 ...... \infty\}$ ?

Comment: a link to the paper you found it in would help.

Comment: sorry for the delay, was communting. [Link](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/386/1/1999-31.pdf) to the paper . The notation is on page 3.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the length-$N$ vector with all elements equal to $1/N$.

Comment: As Abhiram mentionned in his answer, it is indeed a $N$-length vector with all elements equal to $1/N$. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a $N \times 1$ matrix containing $\frac{1}{N}$ in all entries. Since it is in the context of page rank, it represents the teleportation probabilities. $c$ represents the probability with which you will choose the original matrix $M$. With probability $1 - c$, you will just randomnly (uniformly at random, hence the $\frac{1}{N}$) teleport to any of the $n$ vertices in the graph. Normally, $c$ is chosen to be quite large.

Comment: That's something I was wondering about. In the [original paper](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/422/1/1999-66.pdf) they dont talk about $(1-c)$, they instead multiply the vector $E$ by $c$. Is there a revised version of the paper I should know about ? EDIT : E is the $[\frac{1}{N}]_{_{N\times1}}$ vector I was stuck on if I understood it correctly

Comment: Not sure if there is a revised version. Having said that, at the top of page 6 in the link you provided, they say something weird (I haven't read the entire paper, so maybe I just need more context). They say "E is uniform over all webpages with value $\alpha$". Not sure what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: $E$ is just a "rank source" vector to avoid rank sinks from gaining rank to infinity. If 2 pages point at each other but nothing else, and a third page points to one of them then they just increase each other's pageRank to infinity, $E$ is supposed to avoid this by introducing a "history" of the ranks so the algorithm doesn't augment their value past a certain threshold.